# Fontawesome icons not showing up despite vendor CSS being correctly loaded

Tags: font-awesome

[On my page](http://pizzaontime.fr/new/), Fontawesome icons (for example the two one of the extreme top right of the page) don't work any more, despite the fact that the vendor CSS is indeed loaded. Here's how it is loaded from my CSS file:

```
@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `http://pizzaontime.fr/new/wp-content/themes/pot/dist/styles/main.css` you are including font files for FontAwesome locally. The link relative link starts with `../fonts/`, so it should be in here: `http://pizzaontime.fr/new/wp-content/themes/pot/dist/fonts/`, but there is no FontAwesome font file.

Yes, you are including the `*.css` file, but you will have to place the font files in the same structure the FontAwesome CDN is organising them.

**Edit with more details on how to fix it:**

*First approach* (fastest and easiest way): Include the css file in your HTML (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">`). Remove your include in your CSS file then.

*Second approach*: Place the missing font files in `http://pizzaontime.fr/new/wp-content/themes/pot/dist/fonts/`. You can find them [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts).

Comment: In the CSS file of the CDN, you can see they are including font files, which are linked relatively, so the browser will search for them on your server, because you are getting the code of their css file and not just including it. I'll update my answer with more details in a moment.